# while db connect data not insert in table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

 include 'config.php';
 session_start();
 if($_POST)
 {
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
 $message=$_POST['message'];
$sql1="insert into userchat (id,name,email,mobile,message) values ('','$name','$email','$mobile','$message')" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql1);
 }
?>

  <div class="container">
  <br><br><br>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="welcome_get.php" >
        <div class="form-group">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></div><br>

    <div class="form-group">
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    Mobile Number: <input type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile"></div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    Your message : <input type="textarea" name="message" id="message">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </div><br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

insert code not working please check it and let me know what the problem is.

Comment: **STOP** using depricated `mysql_*`API

Comment: You might have sql error. Change 
`$result=mysql_query($sql1);` to 
`$result=mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error()); ` and show us the errors.

Comment: What error do you have ? Doesn't `ID` is the primary key to your table `userchat` ?

Comment: You are providing an empty string for the id.  I'm guessing the table requires an id.

Comment: The primary key is the only thing that MUST BE INSERTED. SO your problem is that you're trying to insert datas without their primary key. And your ID isn't a string so don't but quote around it. You have to insert the primary key too

Comment: Give us the error message please.

Comment: if your `id` is `PK ` and `Auto-increment` then no need to insert in database. it will be automatically inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the id column if it is an auto_increment:

```
$sql1="insert into userchat (name,email,mobile,message) values ('$name','$email','$mobile','$message')" ;
```

Also stop using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements. And check for errors after executing sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to insert datas without the primary key, and that is not allowed.

Here is a solution, add the primary key + 1 like:

```
$ID = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT max(ID) +1 as MaximumID FROM userchat"))['MaximumID'];
$sql1="insert into userchat (id,name,email,mobile,message) values ($ID,'$name','$email','$mobile','$message')" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());
```

If I can add an advice, stop using `mysql_*` because it's depreciate. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: It's better to have auto increment, instead additional select.

Comment: I don't know how is his table built. As I said, it's one solution, not The solution. I just need to know his table or even the error he gets..